# Python will create html file but nothing will be in it

Tags: python

Just started learning python. Trying to understand why the content of the html code won't appear in the file created. It's just blank.

```
message = """<html> 
<head></head>
<body><p>Hello World!</p></body>
</html>"""


my_html_file = open("/Users/Negus/Desktop/hello.html", "w")


my_html_file.write(message)
```

Comment: you need to use `my_html_file.close()` to close the file and write-out the changes.

Comment: Thank you , now i can have peace of mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You must close your file :

```
message = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>Hello World!</p></body>
</html>"""


my_html_file = open("/Users/Negus/Desktop/hello.html", "w")


my_html_file.write(message)

my_html_file.close()
```

Or use this code :

```
with open("/Users/Negus/Desktop/hello.html", "w") as my_html_file:
    my_html_file.write(message)
```